# Core animation from left to right

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-animation

I am building an IOS app.

I am trying to do the following core animation

Text 1 appears at the center
Then replaced by text 2 by having text 2 move from left to right to replace text 1
And then having text 3 move from left to right to replace text 2
Then having text 4 move from left to right to replace text 3.

Each text basically jumps in to replace text 1, 2, 3. So each text rushes in to replace the previous text.
How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use UIView's animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion method to perform these animations. Just nest them inside the completion blocks to chain them together. I think they are for iOS 3.2 and later only though.

```
UILabel *labelText2;  // Can be set up in Interface Builder, linked as IBOutlet
CGRect rectLabel2 = labelText2.frame;
rectLabel2.center = labelText2.superview.center;

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f delay:0.0f options:nil animations:^(){
  labelText2.frame = rectLabel2;  // Animates labelText2 to the center of its container view
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

  // Continue with other animation using another UIView animateWithDuration block...
  UILabel *labelText3; // Setup in Interface Builder on the left outside of the container view
  CGrect rectLabel3 = labelText3.frame;
  rectLabel3.center = labelText3.superview.center;

  [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f delay:0.0f options:nil animations:^(){
    labelText3.frame = rectLabel3;

  } completion:^(BOOL finishedInside) {
    // Nest in Label4, Label5 etc...
  }];
}];
```

More information here
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/animatingviews/animatingviews.html

Comment: Block where introduce in iOS 4.0, but who is supporting less then 4.3 this days anyway ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention if you're using UILabels or CATextLayers. Here's one way to do it with CATextLayers:

First create your layer that you want to animate and add it to the layer tree. I did it in viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  _strings = @[@"Hello world", @"Goodbye cruel world", @"Hello again", @"And again, goodbye!"];

  _textLayer = [CATextLayer layer];
  [_textLayer setString:[_strings objectAtIndex:0]];
  [_textLayer setBounds:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 400.0f, 50.0f)];
  [_textLayer setPosition:[[self view] center]];
  [_textLayer setForegroundColor:[[UIColor orangeColor] CGColor]];
  [_textLayer setAlignmentMode:kCAAlignmentCenter];

  [[[self view] layer] addSublayer:_textLayer];
}
```

Then, hook a button up to this outlet. You'll see a push animation from left to right for each change to the text layer's 'string' property.

```
- (IBAction)didTapChangeText:(id)sender
{
  NSInteger index = arc4random() % [_strings count];

  CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
  [transition setType:kCATransitionPush];
  [transition setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];

  // Tell Core Animation which property you want to use the
  // transition animation for. In this case 'string'
  [_textLayer addAnimation:transition forKey:@"string"];

  // Trigger the animation by setting the string property
  [_textLayer setString:[_strings objectAtIndex:index]];
}
```

From what you've described, this should give you what you're looking for.